# how to use right to left in regex unicode characters

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to detect right-to-left language using a javascript [unicode character class escape regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape), but the line below throws an error

```js
> new RegExp(/[\p{Bidi_Class=Right_to_Left}]/u)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[\p{Bidi_Class=Right_to_Left}]/u: Invalid property name in character class
```

the same error is thrown when using

```js
new RegExp(/[\p{Bidi_Class=Right_to_Left}]/, "u")
```

can you please tell me what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: For some reason, JS doesn't support `Bidi_Class` (https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-runtime-semantics-unicodematchproperty-p)